# Using lambda functions with apply for Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am sorry for asking such a trivial question, but I keep making mistakes when using the `apply function` with a `lambda` function that has input parameters.

See below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["John",1,3],["James",2,3],
            ["Femi",3,4], ["Rita",3,3],
            ["Rita",3,3]], columns=["Name","Age","Height"])


%timeit df["product_AH"] = df[["Age", "Height"]].apply(lambda x,y: x['Age']*y['Height'], axis=1)
```

**Expected output:**

```
    Name    Age  Height  product_AH
0   John    1     3          3
1   James   2     3          6
2   Femi    3     4          12
3   Rita    3     3          9
4   Rita    3     3          9
```

Comment: this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) explains how to use the args in the apply function. For the use case above, df.Age*df.Height should suffice; u dont need apply for that.

Comment: `df[["Age", "Height"]].apply(lambda x: x['Age']*x['Height'], axis=1)` , you dont need 2 args here , though you dont need apply at all , pandas is vectorized to do this

Comment: The function passed to apply will recieve a *single argument* which will a series representing each row, in this case. But apply here is not what you want to use, you want `df['Age'] * df['Hieght']`

Comment: I know this and I read the link before coming here. I would like to use apply. this is just a sample frame.

Comment: thank you @anky_91 your insights were highly valuable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use the "apply" variant, the code should be:

```
df['product_AH'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.Age * row.Height, axis=1)
```

The parameter to the function applied is the whole row.

But much quicker solution is:

```
df['product_AH'] = df.Age * df.Height
```

(1.43 ms, compared to 5.08 ms for the "apply" variant).

This way computation is performed using vectorization, whereas *apply*
refers to each row separately, applies the function to it, then
assembles all results and saves them in the target column, which is
considerably slower.